# Using sed to separate pattern from streams

Tags: sed

I have a file that has log entries on each line like:

```
vert.x-worker-thread-5:606-5 [28281755664384/companyOfflineCaEnricherRSS] [oiq.contentdigestion.PipelineProcessorLink] - CertainClassifierPipelineProcessorInternal COMPLETE [75ms]: http://www.cadc.uscourts.gov/recordings/recordings.nsf/uscadcoralarguments.xml
vert.x-worker-thread-6:524-7 [28281755664384/companyWebAndEventWorkerMultiPass][oiq.contentdigestion.PipelineProcessorLink] - CertainClassifierPipelineProcessorInternal COMPLETE [54ms]: http://a1851.g.akamaitech.net/f/1851/2996/24h/cache.xerox.com/downloads/usa/en/c/CEO_Commitment.pdf
```

Could any one help me in getting the sed command to have the lines processed in to following pattern

```
companyOfflineCaEnricherRSS : CertainClassifierPipelineProcessorInternal 75
companyWebAndEventWorkerMultiPass : CertainClassifierPipelineProcessorInternal 54
```

Comment: Could you please show your own attempts first?

Comment: can you format your input to show clearly the line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sed  command and get you expected output ,

```
sed -r 's/[^\/]+.([^]]+).*- ([^ ]+)[^[]+.([^a-z]+).*/\1 : \2 \3/' FileName

-r, --regexp-extended

          use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

**OutPut :**

companyOfflineCaEnricherRSS : CertainClassifierPipelineProcessorInternal 75
companyWebAndEventWorkerMultiPass : CertainClassifierPipelineProcessorInternal 54